# Mobile safari hide/close event

Tags: events, mobile-safari, iphone

I'm looking for a way to track when a user hides mobile safari by pressing the home button or switching tabs. This doesn't trigger the onunload event, as the tab isn't closed, it's just been put in the background.

Does mobile safari trigger this event at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out there is a 'pagehide' and 'pageshow' events that do get triggered. Only tested on 4.x+